# How to delete an element from a struct - C

Tags: c++, struct

I Would like you to help me in a homework we got from our teacher.
My question is the following: Can you help me in correcting my `ddelete` method? Oh and please don't mark it  as a duplicate, because don't think that there's a solution out there to my problem. (I'm saying that because last night I researched a lot for it)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct{
    long long unsigned num;
    char name[20];
}Telbook;
using namespace std;
int be(Telbook*);
void ki(Telbook[]);
void search (Telbook[]);
void ddelete(Telbook[]);
int count(Telbook[]);

int main(){


setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
printf("\t\t\t  Struktura feladat 1.  \n\n\n");
Telbook tomb[50];
int db;
db=be(tomb);            
ki(tomb);
search(tomb);
ddelete(tomb);
ki(tomb);
system("pause");
}
int be(Telbook *n){
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter phone # and names until the phone # you entered is 0\n");

    /*printf("Kérek egy nevet: ");
    scanf("%s",n->name);*/
    printf("Enter a Phone #: ");
    scanf("%llu",&n->num);

    while(n->num){
        printf("Enter a name: ");
        scanf("%s",n->name);
        i++;
        n++;
        printf("Enter a phone #: ");
        scanf("%llu",&n->num);

    }
    return i;
}
void ki(Telbook n[]){
    int i=0;
    while(n[i].num){

    printf("Name: %s, Phone #: %llu\n",n[i].name,n[i].num);
    i++;
    //n++;
    }

}
void search(Telbook n[]){
    int i=0;
    int dbb;

    char nev[20];
    dbb=count(n);
    printf("Enter the name you're  searching for: ");
    scanf("%s",nev);
    for(i=0;i<dbb;i++){
        if(strcmp(n[i].name,nev)==0)break;

        //n++;
    }
    if(i==dbb){
    printf("The name doesn't exist.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("The name you have searhed for is: %s it's on the %d. index.\n",nev,i+1);
    }
}
int count(Telbook n[]) {
    int i = 0;
    while (n[i].num) {

        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

void ddelete(Telbook n[]){


    int szam,db=count(n),i=0,adat;

        printf("Enter a number you want to delete: ");scanf("%d",&szam);    
        for(i = 0; i < db; i++){
            if( szam == n[i].num){
                for (i = 0; i <  db - 1; i++)
            {
            n[i] = n[i + 1];


           } 
       }        
    }       

}
```

Here's my code. I wrote it as understandable as possible.** My problem is that it doesn't delete the element from the struct.**

Comment: If anyone's going to be able to help you correct it, you need to say what's wrong with it.

Comment: You are using `i` variable as index variable for both for loop in `ddelete`.

Comment: There are other problems. Your code seem to believe that the array `tomb` would be initialized, and that the structure members would have some kind of "zero" value. That's not true. The array, like all other local non-static variables (a.k.a. *automatic* variables) will be uninitialized and have *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) values.

Comment: @4386427: the using statement is the only c++ thing in the code. Is that enough to make it c++? Very interesting idea! BTW: if that kind of code is used in education, I have no idea what students should learn...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude pls check my work below :)

Comment: `typedef struct` -- This is a tell-tale sign you're learning `C`, you're using `C` books, and/or being taught by someone who knows only `C` but was given a C++ course to teach because C++ looks like C.  In C++, there is no need for `typedef struct` -- that is a `C` holdover from the past.  All you need is `struct`.

Comment: @AliDahud: "offensive towards me". No, it is "against" the code you show. Your code is not usable in a productive scenario, not maintainable, bad to read, has a lot of flows and so on. And your code is plain C! If you like to learn C++, you should start with learning object oriented programming as soon as possible. You should take every hint you got here as an idea which let you grow! It is up to you to take the advice you got to be a better programmer. If you don't like criticism, you can't be a programmer. Reviews are part of the job!

Comment: @AliDahud: don't take it personal, no one is saying you did a bad job. There stating that your teacher did that and that you are the victim of it. Looking at the code, I agree with those comments as he's just teaching C with a C++ compiler instead of teaching C++. After all these years, not much has changed about that, which can frustrate a lot of C++ programmers that actually believe C++ ain't that complex when used correctly. (Compared to other popular languages)

Comment: @JVApen I would argue against that. The operators  in C++ are a nightmare. The `::`alone makes me want to claw my eyes out... C++ is to my mind one of the hardest languages to learn to read because the syntax quite complex.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using an array of `Telbook` you can't delete. That is probably what you found by reading. The kind of delete that is referred here is the removal of the space for the element one like to delete. And that is not possible when using array. In C++ Arrays are of fixed size, as your hard disk is of fixed size (you can't delete the space you bought).

Now, deleting may refer to the user point of view, means that provided that the application presents data to user as if some data could be removed such deletion is a matter of coding information (you can delete files, but that is not physical space removal, just logical deletion, data is never presented to you again, that's all).

Then in your case, either you change the way the memory used is managed (for example by using dynamic allocation - new/delete - to allocate and remove space in your running program), or use some kind of coding to represent the fact that some entries in your fixed size array do not correspond to something and are to be considered as "free".

In your case, the function `ki` can guide you:

```
void ki(Telbook n[]){
    int i=0;
    while(n[i].num){    
      printf("Name: %s, Phone #: %llu\n",n[i].name,n[i].num);
      i++;
    } 
}
```

As it is written, valid entries in the array are those that are indexed from the beginning up to the one for which field `num` is 0. So the logic behind the storing is that: any `TelBook` element for which `num` equals to 0 is "free" or is stored at an index greater that an element for which `num` equals to zero.

Then something like:

```
void ddelete(Telbook n[]){
    int szam,db=count(n),i=0,adat;
    printf("Enter a number you want to delete: ");
    scanf("%d",&szam);    
    for(i = 0; i < db; i++) {
       if (szam == n[i].num){
         for (j = i; j <  db - 2; j++) { // copy elements at the end, one pos to the left 
            n[j] = n[j + 1];
         }
         n[db-1].num = 0; // ensure the last element is effectively a free one
         return; // stop here, no need to continue 
       }       
    }       
}
```

But that also suppose that all `TelBook` entries have been correctly initialized, which is not the case, change to (at least):

```
Telbook tomb[50];
tomb[0].num = 0;
```

Some other problems may exists, but you have to work a little bit by yourself now.